# not able to make a call on extension using external sip profile

Tags: freeswitch

I have just installed freeswitch on my system.Right now i am able to register sample extension(s) with external sip profiles
for example :

```
 1000@x.x.x.x:5080
 1001@x.x.x.x:5080
```

now i am dialing 1001 from extension 1000  then freeswitch console its showing me *user not registered* but i am already registered with 1001 extension.

As per my knowledge when i am dial 1001 then its try to call on internal profile that's why its showing user is not registered but from which place i have to change like call goes on my 1001 extension

any suggestions ? any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure sip gateway.

Configuring a sip gateway allows you to connect with outside carriers or other SIP machines.

Gateways are associated with SIP profiles because FreeSWITCH needs to know which IP and port to send traffic to and from in relation to the carrier.

First, you'll need to add a gateway to your SIP profile. Let's assume you're using the default FreeSWITCH configuration. In this case, we'll create a gateway that is attached to the default external profile.

1. Create a file in the conf/sip_profiles/external/ directory named after your gateway
2. Add the following content (note that even if you are not registering, a username and password is required) but replace the highlighted items with your own provider:

   ```
   <gateway name="providerA">
   <param name="realm" value="sip.domain.com"/>
   <param name="username" value="testuser"/>
   <param name="password" value="test"/>
   <param name="register" value="true"/>
   </gateway>
   ```
3. You will access the gateway by using the bridge application with sofia/gateway/
   providerA/number , such as sofia/gateway/providerA/4158867999 . You
   can do this in any dialplan you are using. In this example, edit your dialplan (typically
   the default dialplan in conf/dialplan/default.xml ) and add code to utilize
   the gateway:

   action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/providerA/$1"
4. Issue a reloadxml command in your FreeSWITCH CLI after making the
   mentioned changes.